# "Enter" Keypress to Submit the Form is not working in IE 9/10

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('.inviteClass').keypress(function() {
        if(event.keyCode=='13') {
            doPost();
        }
});
```

Here I have one small requirement. Pressing keyboard Enter to submit the form and it is working fine in FireFox and Chrome, as well as IE 7 and 8, but it is not working in IE9 and IE 10.

Please help me.

Comment: In IE, jQuery will fire keydown(), not keypress() for the arrow keys, because they are considered 'special' keys.

Comment: possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427912/in-ie8-enter-key-in-a-form-does-not-work   and                                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546140/enter-does-not-submit-form-in-ie-because-of-hidden-button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Points to note:**

1. You are missing a closing bracket.
2. Also, change the selector to `window`
3. Use `.on()` function
4. Use the `.which` property of event. See jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)
5. The keycode is an integer - remove the quotes
6. Add a `return false;` to stop the event from bubbling to the form (and possibly submitting the form twice). See [Submitting a form on 'Enter' with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery?rq=1)

**Final code:**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('keydown', function(event) {
        if(event.which == 13) {
            doPost();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the `keypress` function is a shortcut for `.on( "keypress", handler )`, so point `3` is invalid. See also: https://api.jquery.com/keypress/.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.inviteClass').keypress(function (e) {
  c = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if (c == 13) {
    doPost();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;    //<---- Add this line
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use jQuery's event.which, also change '13' to 13 (a closing bracket was also missing):

```
$(function(){
    $('.inviteClass').keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.which == 13) {
            doPost();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. The second last closing bracket should be `});` and not just a `}`.

Answer (score -1):

Please Try to use keydown event and also pass the event object in the function like this

```
$(function(){$('.inviteClass').keydown(function(event){if(event.keyCode=='13'){doPost();}});
```

or

```
$(function(){$('.inviteClass').keypress(function(event){if(event.keyCode=='13'){doPost();}});
```

Hope this will help you

Thanks